# PHP 7 cannot display SQL Server result query when using FOR JSON

Tags: php, json, sql-server, php-7, sqlsrv

I made a RestFull API with PHP 7 for a connection with SQL server. In SQL Server there is the facility to convert a table into JSON directly. With this SQL Server command you can make JSON easy and fast. In your SQL query just use the  command `FOR JSON PATH/AUTO`

Example:

```
SELECT *
FROM [PUT TABLE NAME HERE]
FOR JSON AUTO
```

If  I run in SSMS I can find the value (JSON) from the query like this:

[image]

Exactly as above it runs well in SQL Server.

But the problem is when I want to get the result in PHP with this script, I get an error and when I dump "sqlsrv_query" I get an error message "Boolean(false)"

```
$strmainQuery = "  
   SELECT * 
   FROM TBL_CUSTOMER
   FOR JSON AUTO
 ";

$json =array();
$qmainQuery  = sqlsrv_query($connSys, $strmainQuery, array(), array( "Scrollable" => 'static' ));
var_dump($qmainQuery);
die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));

while($rList = sqlsrv_fetch_array($qmainQuery,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $json[] = $rList;
}
```

The error I get is below:

> bool(false) Array (
> [0] => Array
> (
> [0] => 42000
> [SQLSTATE] => 42000
> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6gOR.png) => 13602
> [code] => 13602
> [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9wOy.png) => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The FOR JSON clause is not allowed in a CURSOR statement.
> [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The FOR JSON clause is not allowed in a CURSOR
> statement.
> )
>
> )

For comparison of whether or not there is also an error in other programming languages, I tried to make a similar script using Adobe Coldfusion, the result of which was a success:

[image]

What is causing the SQL server error I'm encountering, and how can I fix it?

Other SQL Command:
I tried to use this SQL command and i can get value(result) right now but new problem is 'value of json will be truncated when big data query loaded'

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TEMP_DATA_JSON;
WITH ALLDATA (RESULT_JSON) as 
(

    /************************************************ 
    PUT MAIN QUERY IN HERE
    ***********************************************/
    SELECT * 
    FROM TBL_CUSTOMER
    FOR JSON AUTO
    /************************************************ 
    END PUT MAIN QUERY IH HERE 
    ***********************************************/
)
SELECT RESULT_JSON INTO #TEMP_DATA_JSON FROM ALLDATA
SELECT * FROM #TEMP_DATA_JSON
```

Comment: Please can you [edit] your question to include the exact output you get from the code shown - you say "with this script i get error", but don't give the actual error message.

Comment: if your query result is FALSE, executing the query gave an error. This error might vary from connecting to your database or a typo in the query.

Comment: _The FOR JSON clause is not allowed in a CURSOR statement._ Have you tried not specifying cursor options to sqlsrv_query()?